# NetLogo - Setting a parameter to an Integer

Tags: parameters, integer, netlogo

### Setting a function parameter to an integer in NetLogo

After exhausting the Documentation for NetLogo online, I couldn't find a solution to set a parameter (lets call it `r`), to an integer in the function declaration.

In python it is as simple as `WTMC(n, r=25):`

In NetLogo however, I don't know how to set r = 25, without having an error.

How can I set my `WTMC [ n r ]` function to `WTMC [ n r = 25 ]`

So that I can then call my function: `show WTMC [ n ]`, without needing to include the parameter `r`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't directly possible NetLogo. You can get close however by just making two functions:

```
to WTMC [ n ]
  full-WTMC n 25
end

to full-WTMC [ n r ]
  ...
end
```

(In extensions, you can create primitives with optional arguments like this, just not normal netlogo)